# Unattend Installation with virtio drivers doesn't activate network drivers

Tags: windows, powershell, qemu, unattend-file

I try to install a Windows Server VM on a Proxmox host with autounattended installation mode. The VM will be installed and starts as expected, but the network drivers (and so the network configuration) are not available.

I've tried several options together with demo Win 2k19 ISO image and the Virtio drivers ISO image from Fedora.

What I do (with Ansible, but that isn't the issue here):

- mount the Virtio ISO, copy the content to a new location together with the autounattend.xml and some PowerShell scripts.
- pack that location to a new ISO file
- create a VM with two CDROM drives and mount the Win ISO and the Drivers-ISO, also the VM has of course hard disc, network device etc.
- start the VM
- the Windows Installer finds the autounattend.xml on e: and starts an automatic installation
- the autounattend.xml contains paths to the drivers on the Drivers ISO, to find the SCSI hard disc. That works
- but the network drivers are not loaded and so I cannot configure the network via autounattend.
- I tried to build a PowerShell script but it also not enough, the script runs, no errors, but the device manager shows the RedHat Virtio Ethernet adapter with an exclamation mark.
- when I run the virtio-win-gt-x64.msi manually after installation, it says - the software is installed and can only be removed...

... but why is the network driver not working? When I reinstall the MSI package the network comes online.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
  <settings pass="windowsPE">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="{{ bootstrap_host_type }}" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <SetupUILanguage>
        <UILanguage>de-DE</UILanguage>
      </SetupUILanguage>
      <InputLocale>de-DE</InputLocale>
      <SystemLocale>de-DE</SystemLocale>
      <UILanguage>de-DE</UILanguage>
      <UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>
      <UserLocale>de-DE</UserLocale>
    </component>

    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-PnpCustomizationsWinPE" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" processorArchitecture="{{ bootstrap_host_type }}" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <DriverPaths>

        <PathAndCredentials wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="1">
          <Path>E:\{{ bootstrap_host_type }}\{{ bootstrap_os_version }}</Path>
        </PathAndCredentials>

        <PathAndCredentials wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="2">
          <Path>E:\viostor\{{ bootstrap_os_version }}\{{ bootstrap_host_type }}</Path>
        </PathAndCredentials>

        <PathAndCredentials wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="3">
          <Path>E:\NetKVM\{{ bootstrap_os_version }}\{{ bootstrap_host_type }}</Path>
        </PathAndCredentials>
  
        <PathAndCredentials wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="4">
          <Path>E:\Balloon\{{ bootstrap_os_version }}\{{ bootstrap_host_type }}</Path>
        </PathAndCredentials>
  
        <PathAndCredentials wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="5">
          <Path>E:\pvpanic\{{ bootstrap_os_version }}\{{ bootstrap_host_type }}</Path>
        </PathAndCredentials>
  
        <PathAndCredentials wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="6">
          <Path>E:\qemupciserial\{{ bootstrap_os_version }}\{{ bootstrap_host_type }}</Path>
        </PathAndCredentials>
  
        <PathAndCredentials wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="7">
          <Path>E:\qxldod\{{ bootstrap_os_version }}\{{ bootstrap_host_type }}</Path>
        </PathAndCredentials>
  
        <PathAndCredentials wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="8">
          <Path>E:\vioinput\{{ bootstrap_os_version }}\{{ bootstrap_host_type }}</Path>
        </PathAndCredentials>
  
        <PathAndCredentials wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="9">
          <Path>E:\viorng\{{ bootstrap_os_version }}\{{ bootstrap_host_type }}</Path>
        </PathAndCredentials>
  
        <PathAndCredentials wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="10">
          <Path>E:\vioscsi\{{ bootstrap_os_version }}\{{ bootstrap_host_type }}</Path>
        </PathAndCredentials>
  
        <PathAndCredentials wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="11">
          <Path>E:\vioserial\{{ bootstrap_os_version }}\{{ bootstrap_host_type }}</Path>
        </PathAndCredentials>
  
        <PathAndCredentials wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="12">
          <Path>E:\vioserial\{{ bootstrap_os_version }}\{{ bootstrap_host_type }}</Path>
        </PathAndCredentials>

      </DriverPaths>
    </component>
```

...

```
  <settings pass="specialize">

    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="{{ bootstrap_host_type }}" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <OEMInformation>
        <HelpCustomized>false</HelpCustomized>
      </OEMInformation>
      <ComputerName>*</ComputerName>
      <TimeZone>{{ vm_time_zone }}</TimeZone>
      <RegisteredOwner/>
    </component>

    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP" processorArchitecture="{{ bootstrap_host_type }}" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Interfaces>
        <Interface wcm:action="add">
          <Ipv6Settings>
            <DhcpEnabled>false</DhcpEnabled> 
            <Metric>30</Metric> 
            <RouterDiscoveryEnabled>true</RouterDiscoveryEnabled> 
          </Ipv6Settings>
          <Identifier>Ethernet 1</Identifier>
          <UnicastIpAddresses>
            <IpAddress wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="1">{{ network.wan.ipv6.address }}/{{ network.wan.ipv6.prefix }}</IpAddress>
          </UnicastIpAddresses>
          <Routes>
            <Route wcm:action="add">
              <Identifier>1</Identifier> 
              <Metric>10</Metric> 
              <NextHopAddress>{{ network.wan.ipv6.gateway }}</NextHopAddress> 
              <Prefix>0</Prefix> 
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </Interface>
      </Interfaces>
    </component>
```

...

```
  <settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="{{ bootstrap_host_type }}" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <AutoLogon>
        <Username>administrator</Username>
        <Password>
          <Value>{{ vm_admin_pass }}</Value>
          <PlainText>true</PlainText>
        </Password>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <LogonCount>3</LogonCount>
      </AutoLogon>

      <FirstLogonCommands>

        <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
          <CommandLine>%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\NewNetworkWindowOff /f</CommandLine>
          <Order>1</Order>
          <Description>Disable Network Discovery Prompt</Description>
        </SynchronousCommand>

        <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
          <CommandLine>powershell -File e:\scripts\configure.ps1</CommandLine>
          <Description>Install and configure common tasks</Description>
          <Order>2</Order>
        </SynchronousCommand>
```

...

and here the PowerShell script.

```
# Create Workdir
$BasePath = "C:\Windows\Temp\Install"
New-item $BasePath -itemtype directory

# Add RedHat to Trusted Publisher
$CertName = "redhat.cer"
$CertFile = Join-Path $BasePath -ChildPath $CertName

$Cert = (Get-AuthenticodeSignature "e:\pvpanic\{{ bootstrap_os_version }}\{{ bootstrap_host_type }}\pvpanic.sys").SignerCertificate
$ExportType = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Cert

[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($CertFile, $Cert.Export($ExportType))
Import-Certificate -FilePath $CertFile -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPublisher

Start-Sleep -s 5

# install Virtio Drivers
Start-Process msiexec -Wait -ArgumentList '/i e:\virtio-win-gt-x64.msi /log "C:\Windows\Temp\Install\qemu-drivers.log" /qn /passive /norestart ADDLOCAL=ALL'
```

The VM is configured with

- pc-i440fx-6.1
- cputype=host
- virtio SCSI single with scsi0
- net0 as virtio device with bridge=vmbr0, firewall=1 - no DHCP available
- ide0 with media=cdrom,local:iso/win2k19.iso
- ide1 with media=cdrom,local:iso/drivers.iso

What is wrong with my installation, that the Windows system knows the RedHat ethernet adapter but isn't really using the desired drivers? I've also installed automatically the RedHat certificate (to avoid questions during installation). But I cannot use that during autounattend (at that moment I cannot install certificates).

Also I tried to run the msiexec direct on command line. Still the same. It detects, that the software is already installed. Then I try to install the software again and via msiexec that installation runs in 2-3sek and then it is installed (which is to fast). When I do it manually with the GUI, everything is fine.

The msiexec command is

```
msiexec /I e:\virtio-win-gt-x64.msi /qn /passive /log ".." ADDLOCAL=ALL
```

The generated logfiles is about 130k in size and contains no errors. I wander if

```
DIFXAPP: Info: This is a no-op custom action for component CMP_WinServer2019_netkvm.
```

is correct. I'm using version 0.1.208 from [Fedora](https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/latest-virtio/virtio-win.iso).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just using `pnputil` to install the drivers and bypassing the msi installer entirely?

In my environment (Proxmox VE 6.2-6 running Server 2019 Core VM's) I mount the CD and then run:

```
Get-ChildItem E:\ -Recurse -Filter "*.inf" | ForEach-Object { pnputil.exe /add-driver $_.FullName /install }
```

Which results in all the applicable drivers being installed and selected properly.

If you need the QEMU agent to be installed to support ACPI commands and the like then you can add:

```
$Installer = "qemu-ga-x86_64.msi"
if ([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem -eq $false)
{ 
    $Installer = "qemu-ga-i386.msi"
}
Start-Process msiexec -ArgumentList "/I e:\GUEST-AGENT\$Installer /qn /norestart" -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried that - but the result is the same. The network device (the only problem) stays with the exclamation mark in the device manager. Only when I install the driver manually via "GUI" the network device is correctly installed. even without PowerShell but only with msiexec ...

Comment: That's very strange indeed.
The other option you could try is building a gold image with something like MDT/SCCM and injecting the drivers in before doing a sysprep.
That might convince windows to use the right drivers during install.

Answer (score 2):

As response to my own question. Using the MSI packages seems to have a strange problem with the arguments. It looks like the msiexec installation is ignoring the ADDLOCAL attribute and/or installs "something", but not the correct drivers. Also it is strange, that the concrete driver installation does not have any effect. It seems to me, there is something missing in automatic installation process.

I cannot say why, but using the virtio-guest-tools.exe seems to work.... more or less. I need to install, uninstall and install the software again - then the network device comes online and I can configure it via New-NetIPAddress.

```
Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow -FilePath 'e:\virtio-win-guest-tools.exe' -ArgumentList '/s /qn'
Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow -FilePath 'e:\virtio-win-guest-tools.exe' -ArgumentList '/s /qn /uninstall'
Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow -FilePath 'e:\virtio-win-guest-tools.exe' -ArgumentList '/s /qn'
```

So - this works for me. But this is ugly, unnormal and should never be the correct answer.